# Unable to capture values from a list and convert "K" to "000"

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to Python and learning each and everyday. I want to convert all the price values from string "3K" to  "3000" on a python data frame. Unable to proceed. Please help

I am learning Python on my own, read a lot on the internet, watch a lot of youtube video tutorials.  This is just a tutorial that I fail to complete.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 

def regex_filter(val):
    if val:
        #new_values = ' '
        mo = re.search('\d+[kK]',val)
        if mo:
            print("The length of mo is ",mo)
            new_values = str(mo) + "000"
            print("The New value is ",new_values)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False 


if __name__ == "__main__": 



    df = pd.read_csv('ProductID_price.csv', encoding='utf8')

    df_filtered = df[df['price'].apply(regex_filter)]
```

```
product_id      product_name                price
0001        Mares XR Kevlar Diving Dry Suit     3K
0002        Beuchat Abyss Dry Diving Dry Suit       2050
0003        Typhoon Scuba Dive Dry Suit         1.5K
0004        Scubapro Evertech Drysuit Men           4,059.99
```

Comment: Are you expecting "K", "M", "B", etc or just "K"?

Comment: Convert to a string, use the replace, and then convert back to float. `price = float( str( price).replace( 'k', '000'))`  - or if you will be using multiple letters as cs95 asked create a function that handles all the cases.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I want to maintain consistency on the Price list and when staff enter the pricing in alphanumeric such as “3K” to mean “3000” and “1.5K” to mean “1500, I want to change all to numbers.  I only expect a “K” on each pricing if the staff enter incorrectly and inconsistently. It is OK to capture in String format and I will convert it to float later on.

Comment: There is something that I do not understand, in my code, I want to display the “mo” value and it gives me 

The mo value is : -> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='3K'>

Comment: I took your suggestion and modified my codes and I still could not extract the numeric values of "3K". It also would not convert string to float.  Here is my modified codes:

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 

def regex_filter(val):
    new_price = val
    if val:
        price = ' '
        mo = re.search('\d+[kK]',val)
        if mo:
            price = str(price).replace('K','000')
            print("The New value is ",price)
            new_price = price
            return new_price
        else:
            return new_price
    else:
        return new_price


if __name__ == "__main__": 

    df = pd.read_csv('ProductID_price.csv', encoding='utf8')
    df['price'] = df['price'].apply(regex_filter)